# How to create an abstract function to get data from mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I want to create a abstract function to get all collections with mongoose and it will receive or not the parameters to use in the populate method. So, I have this code now:

```
async function getCollection(model, relatedFields) {   
 if (!relatedFields) relatedFields = [];  
    try {
      const collection = await model.find()
        .populate(relatedFields[0] ? relatedFields[0] : '')
        .populate(relatedFields[1] ? relatedFields[1] : '')
        .populate(relatedFields[2] ? relatedFields[2] : '');
      return collection;
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
 }
```

It works, but this repeated populate method seems to me inefficient.

There is a way to do this smarter?
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to build your query dynamically and then execute.

```js
async function getCollection(Model, relatedFields = []) {
  try {
    let query = Model.find();

    for (let relatedField of relatedFields) {
      if (relatedField) {
        query = query.populate(relatedField);
      }
    }

    const docs = await query();
    return docs;
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's a better approach. Thanks